# Как реализовать исполнение JavaScript-кода внутри IFrame?

Tags: jquery, javascript, html, dom

Здравствуйте.

Есть iframe, который создается в результате загрузки страницы.

```
var object_preview = $('#preview');

var iframe = $('<iframe id="preview_frame">'),
    iframe_body,
    iframe_head;

object_preview.html(iframe);

setTimeout(function() {
   var doc = iframe[0].contentWindow.document;
   iframe_body = $('body', doc);
   iframe_head = $('head', doc);
}, 1);
```

При нажатии определенной кнопки, в head-тег этого iframe вставляется JS-код (jQuery), который необходимо исполнить внутри дерева iframe.

Обработчик нажатия кнопки:

```
$('#run').click(function() {
        iframe_body.append('<script type="text/javascript">\
                $(document).ready(function() {\
                        $(".test").click(function() { alert(true); });\
                });\           
        </script>');
});
```

В данный момент код не выполняется, как это можно реализовать?

Элемент с классом test находится внутри дерева iframe; код необходимо исполнить также внутри iframe, а не на всей странице.

HTML-структура:

[image]

Comment: а зачем вам исполнять код внутри iframe ? это точно нужно ? если да то `document.createElement('script')` и добавляйте его чилдом к iframe head,

Comment: и $(document).ready() бессмысленно делать.

Comment: @eicto, попробовал сделать как Вы сказали, создать элемент при клике на кнопку с идентификатором run, но, к сожалению, все осталось прежним. Насчет window.$ можно поподробнее?

Comment: @eicto, огромное Вам спасибо. Преобразуйте комментарий в ответ, я поставлю Вам галочку.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery должен быть загружен в iframe.

```
var object_preview = $('#preview');
var iframe = $('<iframe id="preview_frame">'),
    iframe_body,
    doc,
    iframe_head;

object_preview.html(iframe);

setTimeout(function() {
   doc = iframe[0].contentWindow.document;  
   var jQueryScript=doc.createElement('script');   
   iframe_body = $(doc.body);   
   iframe_head = $(doc.head);
   $(jQueryScript).appendTo(doc.head);
   jQueryScript.src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-git2.js';
   var button=$("<button>").addClass('test').text('test').appendTo(iframe_body);
});

$('#run').click(function() {
        var script=doc.createElement('script');
        iframe_body.append(script);
        script.innerHTML='$(".test").click(function() { alert(true); });';
    $(this).hide(); //потому что два раза добавлять сюда нельзя.
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/85Gbx/